# MySQL syntax error detected, but don't what is wrong?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I typed the following code
And I don't know what's wrong with my code.

```
CREATE TABLE SlotGame
(
  gID CHAR(12),
  jackpot DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  sID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(gID),
  FOREIGN KEY(gID) REFERENCES Game(gID),
  FOREIGN KEY(sID) REFERENCES Slot(sID),
);
```

The following is shown to me:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 9

Hope someone can tell me what's wrong.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please note that actually the tables 'Game' and 'Slot' have already created by me.

Comment: Is line 9 the `);` line?  If so, then what's wrong with line 8?

Answer (score 6):

You just need to remove the last comma:

```
CREATE TABLE SlotGame
(
  gID CHAR(12),
  jackpot DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  sID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(gID),
  FOREIGN KEY(gID) REFERENCES Game(gID),
  FOREIGN KEY(sID) REFERENCES Slot(sID) <-- comma removed
);
```